# 4004 RIA Service error - Remote database

Tags: silverlight, ria

After finaly be abble to setup my silverlight app with RIA, I call the following code to get my list of citie objects from my remote database:

```
_context = context;
var load =_context.Load(_context.GetCitiesQuery());
_cities = new ObservableCollection<City>(load.Entities);
```

I get no errors, but also no data. After using fiddler I do see that I get a responce looking like this:

> @GetCitiesResponsehttp://tempuri.org/@GetCitiesResult aDomainServices i)http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance^
>   TotalCount�^
>   RootResults b4http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gymsport.Web_City_CityID�_CityName�Oelegem_PostCode�� _City_CityID�_CityName�Ranst_PostCode�� _City_CityID�_CityName�Emblem_PostCode��    _City_CityID�_CityName�Ranst_PostCode��

Which is a lot of rubbish, but between the lines you can read it returns a couple of cities.
But for some reason my silverlight app doens't pick up on those.

Any suggestions on how to look for a solution?

Thanks in advance.
Grtz
T

Comment: You wouldn't believe it, but my webhost is still running .NETv2..

Comment: Nope, wasn't the problem... MVC 3 seems to be blocking my path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I had to work with the EntityList object to convert the result of the query to an observable collection. Thank you Firefox ErrorConsole :)